# Installation of Kivy garden

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, kivy

I'm working on my python app with Kivy 1.10.0 under Ubuntu.
I tried various times to install some packages from Kivy garden and followed these official instructions:
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.garden.html

When I enter `pip install kivy-garden`
it says:

> Requirement already satisfied: kivy-garden in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from kivy-garden)
>   Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->kivy-garden)
>   Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->kivy-garden)
>   Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->kivy-garden)
>   Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->kivy-garden)

But when I try to install a package in the next step with for example:

```
garden install graph
```

it always just says

> The program 'garden' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install garden-of-coloured-lights

I really can't figure out what the problem is and can't find proper help in the web. Do you see any mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.

Unfortunately that didn't work for me either. I still don't know what causes the issue but I solved it for myself by installing the virtual machine and running Kivy under windows in an Linux environment.
That way, it was possible to install everything properly.

Best wishes

Answer (score 2):

After a few work arounds
I did this
clone garden with **git clone https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.git**
then **cd garden/bin**
sudo **chmod +x garden**
garden install 
example **garden install xpopup**
You can **ln -s garden /usr/bin/garden to make it easier**
I use *Ubuntu 17.04*
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This also happened for me i am using ubuntu , This is how i solved the issue.

1. Don't type command `garden install graph` inside the "activated" virtual environment command line.
2. If you are using some IDE like vscode they by default activate the virtual environment.
3. instead use terminal go inside your project directory without activating the virtual environment then execute

   ```
   garden install graph
   ```

Comment: this worked for me, i tried with 'sudo garden install graph' and give permission chmod 755 to garden dir and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

only a little correction, the ln command must include the full path

ln -s /home/davidea/garden/bin/garden /usr/bin/garden

i put mine on my home directory and i'm working on debian jessie